# R dplyr mutate colnames

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi,

I'm having an issue with data frames where when I run the following code:

```
test <- data.frame( col <- c(1,2,3,4))
```

my column name is "col <- c(1,2,3,4)" instead of just "col"

This also happens if I mutate:

```
test <- test %>% mutate(newcol <- ifelse(1==1, 0,0))
```

column name is now `newcol <- ifelse(1==1, 0,0)` instead of just `newcol`

Is there a way to define the colnames right the first time and not having to rename them.

Thanks

Comment: use `newcol = ifelse(...` instead of `newcol <- ifelse(...`

Comment: in the first case, `data.frame()` is capturing `col`, but it also becomes an object in the global env. Not so inside of `mutate()` (I believe).